# Vue <script setup>, unable to use defineProps and defineEmits without importing it

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props, vue-sfc, vue-script-setup

As per the [official documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-and-defineemits),

> `defineProps` and `defineEmits` are **compiler macros** only
> usable inside `<script setup>`. They do not need to be
> imported and are compiled away when `<script setup>` is
> processed.

###### The problem definition

I'm not able to use `defineProps` and `defineEmits` in `<script setup>` without importing it. Please refer to the error screenshot attached below.

[image: not able to use defineProps without importing it in]

###### The vue code which I'm executing

```js
<!-- HelloWorld.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>{{ props.message }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
// import { defineProps } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
</script>
```

###### The environment details for reference:

| vue | ^3.2.6 (3.2.19) |
| --- | --- |
| vue-cli | @vue/cli 5.0.0-beta.4 |
| node: | v14.16.1 |
| npm | 6.14.12 |

Answer (score 6):

We can resolve this issue with one of the below solutions.

1. Create Vue project with Vite. Follow this [link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) for more information.
   `yarn create vite <project-name> --template vue`
2. Add below rules in your eslint configuration file. Follow this [link](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#does-not-work-well-with-script-setup) for more information.

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  extends: ['plugin:vue/base'],
  rules: {
    'vue/script-setup-uses-vars': 'error',
  }
}
```

Comment: In second solution it's wrong link. It should be: [link](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#compiler-macros-such-as-defineprops-and-defineemits-generate-no-undef-warnings) , and code should be: `module.exports = { env: { 'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true } }`

Comment: @Lothir: I guess it depends regarding the code. Adding the rules of the answer worked fine for me, while setting the env in your suggestion gave me an error on linting...

Answer (score 1):

use first script:

```
<script setup>
// import { defineProps } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ props.message }}</h1>
</template>
```

and you can use typescript:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<Props>();

interface Props {
  message: string
}

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ props.message }}</h1>
</template>
```